# What happens if I send false to super.viewWillAppear()

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle, viewwillappear

Will behaviour of view getting loaded or appearance will change if I send hardcoded `false` instead of `animated` to `super.viewWillAppear`.

I tried this code and nothing different happened so I am confused.

Comment: just animation is omitted

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear)

> animated: If true, the view is being added to the window using an animation....